# Is it possible to reverse-calculate prices based on indicator value?

Tags: mql4

Regularly, we calculate the current RSI(14) using function `iRSI(..., 14)`. However, is there a neat way to make some vice versa calculations in MQL, like 'I've known the previous 13 bars, what should be the close price for 14th bar so that the RSI(14) will be equal to 80'?

I hope the last solution will be drill through the algorithm of RSI, since I want to reverse-calculate some more complicated indicators like Boll bands.

No need to give me the complete coding - just some thought will be enough.

Comment: It is an interesting question, and seems it makes practical sense in some cases. Easiest is probably to build calculations in excel to receive same rsi values, then to create a formulae to compute close of the last candle with known RSI. Some work is needed, but nothing extraordinary

Comment: Have to agree with @DanielKniaz above. Probably to do this in Excel. You could also take into account normal distributions for that calculation to be 80, and factor those in to get some interesting results.